# How to groupby on a column while doing sort on another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the a `df`,

```
   date    amount    code    id
2018-01-01   50       12      1
2018-02-03   100      12      1
2017-12-30   1        13      2
2017-11-30   2        14      2
```

I want to `groupby` `id`, while in each group the date is also sorted in ascending or descending order, so I can do the following,

```
grouped = df.groupby('id')

a = np.where(grouped['code'].transform('nunique') == 1, 20, 0)
b = np.where(grouped['amount'].transform('max') > 100, 20, 0)
c = np.where(grouped['date'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().dropna().sum()).dt.days < 5, 30, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the data within each group by using [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
grouped = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: g.sort_values('date', ascending=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answer, if you wish indexes to remain as they were, you might consider the following :
    import pandas as pd

```
df = {'a':[1,2,3,0,5], 'b':[2,2,3,2,5], 'c':[22,11,11,42,12]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
e = (df.groupby(['c','b', 'a']).size()).reset_index()
e = e[['a', 'b', 'c']]
e = e.sort_values(['c','a'])
print(e)
```